# Using pjsua for android

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, pjsip

Greetings to everyone!

I'm trying to compile pjsua using the following branch:
http://svn.pjsip.org/repos/pjproject/branches/projects/android/. I've
tried to do a push (adb push pjsua /data/local/) to my Android-sdk
emulator but, when I've tried to execute it via adb shell, the Android
LogCat gave me the following SIGFAULT error: where am I wrong? Thanks
in advance.

```
F/libc    (  464): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x000000f0 (code=1)
I/DEBUG   (   33): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (   33): Build fingerprint:'generic/sdk/generic:4.0.3/MR1/237985:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (   33): pid: 464, tid: 464  >>> ./pjsua-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi <<<
I/DEBUG   (   33): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 000000f0
I/DEBUG   (   33):  r0 ffffffff  r1 beef7c30  r2 beef7c30  r3 ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (   33):  r4 00000000  r5 00000000  r6 00000000  r7 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   33):  r8 00000000  r9 00000000  10 00000000  fp 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   33):  ip 4003c4b9  sp beef7c60  lr 4003c4b1  pc b000469a cpsr 00000030
I/DEBUG   (   33):  d0  00000000bd6bc8e3  d1  0000000000000000 
I/DEBUG   (   33):  d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   33):  d4  0000000000000000  d5  41c8f0a46e800000
I/DEBUG   (   33):  d6  3f50624dd2f1a9fc  d7  c18af9670cce266f
I/DEBUG   (   33):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   33):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   33):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   33):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   33):  scr 00000010
I/DEBUG   (   33):
I/DEBUG   (   33):          #00  pc b000469a  /system/bin/linker
I/DEBUG   (   33):          #01  pc 000264ac  /system/lib/libc.so (__set_errno)
I/DEBUG   (   33):
I/DEBUG   (   33): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (   33): b0004678 95004840 44784a40 4d414b40 447b447a @H..@JxD@KAMzD{D
I/DEBUG   (   33): b0004688 682d447d f44f9103 95017140 f0009402 }D-h..O.@q......
I/DEBUG   (   33): b0004698 f8d4ff67 b10330f0 f8d44798 b17000e0 g....0...G....p.
I/DEBUG   (   33): b00046a8 10e4f8d4 f7ff2200 2000f9b5 f8d4e007 ....."..... ....
I/DEBUG   (   33): b00046b8 f04f20a8 f04230ff f8c40102 b00710a8 .O..0B......... 
I/DEBUG   (   33):
I/DEBUG   (   33): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (   33): 4003c490 f240b507 9300736c 33fff04f 466b9301 ..@.ls..O..3..kF
I/DEBUG   (   33): 4003c4a0 fd80f7ff bf00bd0e 4604b510 fe90f7ec ...........F....
I/DEBUG   (   33): 4003c4b0 f04f6004 bd1030ff 0ffff110 db02b510 .`O..0..........
I/DEBUG   (   33): 4003c4c0 f7ff4240 bd10fff1 48214603 4478b5f0 @B.......F!H..xD
I/DEBUG   (   33): 4003c4d0 b0976800 68022150 4620ac01 92154e1d .h..P!.h.. F.N..
I/DEBUG   (   33):
I/DEBUG   (   33): stack:
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c20  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c24  4003c4c7  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c28  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c2c  4002f477  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c30  b00144c4
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c34  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c38  10000000
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c3c  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c40  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c44  4002f49b  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c48  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c4c  0000c090 /data/local/pjsua-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c50  b00144c4
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c54  0000c070 /data/local/pjsua-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c58  df0027ad
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c5c  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   33): #01 beef7c60  00000001
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c64  beef7d47  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c68  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c6c  beef7d6d  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c70  beef7d82  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c74  beef7d92  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c78  beef7dba  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c7c  beef7df7  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c80  beef7e10  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c84  beef7e2a  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c88  beef7f55  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c8c  beef7f68  [stack]  
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c90  beef7f83  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c94  beef7fa0  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c98  beef7fb3  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7c9c  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7ca0  00000010
I/DEBUG   (   33):     beef7ca4  000030d7
```

**EDIT 1**: I must remark that I already know solutions such as csipsimple. Anyway, I'm interested to resolve my cross-compiling issue with Android-ndk's tools.

Comment: have you solved your issue???? please help me if you have solved it because i am also having the same issue.

Comment: Yeah, It's been my undergraduated thesis. https://diasp.org/posts/1500662

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying to use an android device instead?
I red in the android website that the android simulator is usually not compatible with sip stacks.

Comment: Well, I've finished my work now... Thanks anyhow http://jackbergus.alwaysdata.net/projects/android-presentation.tar.gz